# Increase GTK+ 2 icon size?

Tags: gtk, gtk2

For use with a HiDPI screen, I would like to increase toolbar and menu item icons in GTK+ 2, possibly to 48×48 px.

For the Gimp, I am able to increase tool icons by specifying in the theme's `gtkrc`:

```
GimpToolPalette::tool-icon-size   = dialog
```

As far as I can tell, if there are no icons of the specified size available, smaller ones are scaled up. Great!

For *all* GTK+ 2 applications I tried increasing icon size by specifying in `~/.gtkrc-2.0`:

```
gtk-toolbar-icon-size = GTK_ICON_SIZE_DIALOG
```

However, this has no effect, at least in the applications that I tested, for example [Geeqie](http://geeqie.sourceforge.net/). Here the icons are still small.